# In $\operatorname{Hol}(\Bbb{Z}_{10})$, is every mapping from $G\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ just an identity mapping?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, holomorph

Consider $f: G\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ where $G=\Bbb{Z}_{10}$. Since this is equivalent to considering $G\rtimes_f G$, we know that $f$ is defined as $f_a(b)=aba^{-1}$.

There are four automorphisms of $G$, which we will say are $\{c_1,c_3,c_7,c_9\}$ defined as $c_k: z\mapsto kz\mod 10$.

Then, $f_a(b)$ is defined as $f_a(c_k)=a+c_k-a$. But since $G$ is abelian, we can then very simply say that $f_a(c_k)=c_k$. Ergo, for every $a\in G, f_a: c_k\mapsto c_k$.

Is this sound reasoning? I keep worrying that I should be taking the multiplicative inverse instead of the additive, but then again, for many elements (like 2), there *is no* multiplicative inverse.

Additionally, is there a perhaps more instructive example where the automorphism mappings $f_a(b)$ don't just map an automorphism onto itself? Thank you!

Comment: The inverse  must be taken with respect to  the group operation, which in this case is addition. Conjugation in an abelian group is always trivial, so look for examples in non-abelian groups.

Comment: The map from $G$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ has kernel $Z(G)$, so in the case of abelian $G$, the map is trivial.